# how to Extract Audio from video with spring boot java in linux or windows system with ffmpeg coding part need guidance

Tags: spring-boot, ffmpeg

I got this command but don't know the how to configure it for project on command line?

String[] command = {"-y", "-i", filename, "-vn",
"-ar", "44100", "-ac", "2", "-b:a", "256k", "-f", "mp3" + fileStorageLocation};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] command = {"ffmpeg",
                "-i", DIRECTORY + fileName, "-vcodec", "copy", "-an", DIRECTORY+"no_" + fileName
        };
        try {
            Process process = runtime.exec(command);
            LOGGER.info("Process"+process);
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();
            LOGGER.info("Started video with exit code: {}", exitValue);
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            LOGGER.info("stdInput" +stdInput.readLine());
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            LOGGER.info("stdError" +stdError);

            // read the output from the command
            StringBuilder normalOutputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                LOGGER.info("This is ffmpeg try  while block");
                normalOutputBuffer.append(line);
                if (!line.contains("Done:")) {
                    normalOutputBuffer.append("\n");
                }

            }
            if (!normalOutputBuffer.toString().isEmpty()) {
                LOGGER.info("video generation ended successfully. \n {}", normalOutputBuffer.toString());
            }

            // read any errors from the command
            StringBuilder errorOutputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                errorOutputBuffer.append(line);
                errorOutputBuffer.append("\n");
            }
            if (!errorOutputBuffer.toString().isEmpty()) {
                LOGGER.info("video generation ended with failure. \n {}", errorOutputBuffer.toString());
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.error("video generation was interrupted.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error during video generation.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
```